# remove ../src/components from sourcemap generated using rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

I am trying to create a package using typescript, rollup and react, the problem is when I build the package, in the generated sourcemap, it will include `../src/components/*` files that does not exist in built folder (it includes path to actual src folder), and then it causes problems when you install the package. how can I remove these pathes or include src folder inside build folder? here are my config files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es5" ,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true ,
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "strict": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.build.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "src/stories/**"]
}
```

and rollup.config.js:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

const pkg = require("./package.json");

const inputFileName = "src/index.ts";
const moduleName = pkg.name.replace(/^@.*\//, "");
const author = pkg.author;
const banner = `
  /**
   * @license
   * author: ${author}
   * ${moduleName}.js v${pkg.version}
   * Released under the ${pkg.license} license.
   */
`;

export default [
  {
    input: inputFileName,
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: "true",
        banner
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: "true",
        banner
      }
    ],
    plugins: [peerDepsExternal(), resolve(), commonjs(), typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.build.json" }), postcss(), terser()]
  },
  {
    input: "dist/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.css$/]
  }
];
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am running into the same issue

Comment: @LeventeBerky: unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: I solved it in a way that I just set `sourcemap: "false"` evrywhere. It's not optimal for older projects but for ES and CJS packages in modern projects it should not be a problem. You can see my setup [here](https://github.com/brumik/design-system-composer/blob/main/rollup.config.js) - Though if you are able to figure it out I'd be happy if you'd shared.

Comment: @LeventeBerky yes, if we set `sourcemap: "false"`,  we do not get the error, but source map isn't generated too.